# Add error code to /topbar/get-unread-counts JSON when not logged in

Tags: feature-request, notifications

I'm creating a little UserScript that shows notification about new messages/posts/notifications on several websites. For all Stack Exchange communities I just check one URL:
`http://stackexchange.com/topbar/get-unread-counts`, which returns JSON like `{"UnreadInboxCount":0,"UnreadRepCount":0,"UnreadNonRepCount":0}`. Unfortunately when I'm not logged in it doesn't indicate it. JSON stays the same, all counts are zeros. Simply adding some error code when not logged in would solve it.

I know it doesn't affect Stack Exchange much, but I just don't want to load additionally full webpage to check log in state.

Comment: That URL is not API, the API tag is meant for using the actual API as described here: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs

Comment: @ShadowWizard roger that! All tags I added were in `suggested tags`.

Comment: oh, lol. Well, you used lots of key words, the automated system can't possibly know the reason behind it... :)

Answer (score 3):

The request that you are borrowing (`//stackexchange.com/topbar/get-unread-counts`) **is not part of [the publicly provided API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/user-unread-notifications)**.

You could switch to using the API, but that can be a hassle because those particular API routes require API authentication (OAuth2) in addition to normal web page authentication.

But **a quick workaround**, to tell if your zero results are due to not being logged-in, is to check the `StackExchange` object provided on every SE page. Like so:

```js
if ( <<JSON is all zeros>> ) {
    if (StackExchange.options.user.isRegistered) {
        console.log ("You have no messages. Sorry.");
    }
    else {
        console.log ("You need to log in, to see unread counts.");
    }
}
```

---

It doesn't make sense for SE developers to add an error code to that *internal* AJAX.  From SE's perspective, just returning zeros for an anonymous user is good UI behavior. And, it's not an error (or even particularly worrisome) when an anonymous user visits the page.

The official API is provided to accommodate third-party developers.  You can request enhancements for it.

But the *internal* AJAX is for Stack Exchange.  We use it at our own risk and asking for changes to it, when they do not help *Stack Exchange's* purposes and when an API is already provided, is unreasonable.

Comment: That's the point, API requires authentication and I want it to keep it simple. Greasemonkey's `GM_xmlhttpRequest` loads pages from any website just like your browser. With cookies and all. I don't want to load any additional page. 

The best website I've found is [Disqus](https://disqus.com/). It uses API with what seems to be anonymous API key. And it returns JSON with error code when not logged in. [Steam](http://steamcommunity.com/) returns `null` which can be parsed with `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Generally I know using internal calls and not API can break my script but I want to keep it simple: both for creating new [modules](https://gist.github.com/Tithen-Firion/cd7566d5c1064df07d962207af7535ec) and for using it

Comment: Well, then you have your workaround in this answer. ... Expecting SE to alter their internal workings to accommodate this when they already supply an API is not reasonable. ... PS: [I might have a passing familiarity with that `GM_xmlhttpRequest()` thing.](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/gm-xmlhttprequest/topusers) :)

Comment: PS.  You are confusing Disqus' **API** with **internal** calls not meant for third party use. They're two different kinds of things.

Comment: Well all the URLs I'm using in this script are internal calls because of hassle with using API. Disqus's one *looks* like API call, but uses cookies (and public Disqus API key) for authentication, so you're right. I knew it is unlikely that SE will change that, but it didn't hurt to ask. ;)